# How to forward a request between two flow xml

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I am having two flow XML in my application. Consider it as A and B.  In  flow A, I am posting my values in one view state (like login credentials). Its processing the values and executing some action state. After completing the execution, I need to go to flow B( like payment flow).

Here when I am going to flow B, I am using redirect. So it is again going to browser and making a HTTP 302 an then the B flow is executed.

Is there any way to remove this redirection. I tried with forwarding. but its not working. Is there any solution.    This browser redirection is causing lot of issues in my application. Do we have any server side redirection between flows without any browser interaction.

Comment: Show flow.xml for details.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <action-state id="start">
  -----------
  </action-state>
 
    <view-state id="ccccc" model="model" view="view name">
    <on-render>
   <evaluate expression=""/>  
  </on-render> 
        <transition on="next" to="end" />
      
    </view-state>
 <end-state id="end" view="redirect:b.do"/>
</flow>

Comment: i removed the logic and this is how i redirecting from flow a to flow b

Comment: @shankarmbtech Maybe you are after the wrong solution what are you hoping to achieve by avoiding the redirection?

Comment: It sounds like you want to look at sub-flows? We implemented your exact scenario using sub flows, where we had a main flow (eg: your flow A) which called out to a payment process as a sub flow (eg: your flow B). The neat thing about sub flows is that you can pass data into and out of the flow as normal flowscope variables, without having to expose them as query string params (which you really dont want to do for a payment process :) )